# Question about software developing tool closed. Should be reopened

Tags: support, closed-questions, reopen-closed

This closed question is about a tool: [How to change Visual Studio Code's autocomplete to be the same as Visual Studio Community's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65766986/i-would-like-to-change-the-settings-of-vscode-to-be-similar-to-visual-studio)

The reason given, as:

> We don’t allow questions seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more. You can edit the question so it can be answered with facts and citations.

According to: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

> but if your question generally covers…
>
> - software tools commonly used by programmers;

Even in the exceptions it says:

> 7. Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.

In my opinion it is on-topic.

Comment: Yes, the question is on-topic. It's asking about how to enable a very specific feature in a programming tool that's commonly used by programmers. I've voted to reopen.

Comment: I agree that this question is on-topic; however, as has been noted in the comments after this meta question was posted, it appears to possibly be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43247742/208273).  However, I'm not certain, since the answers don't seem to agree...perhaps someone more familiar with the tools could chime in.

Comment: @RyanM You say they don't seem to agree... yet both the answer on the post and multiple answers on the duplicate suggest attempting toggling *"editor.formatOnType"*